# Save model from drawing

Tags: vba, save, solidworks

I have VBA code to issue drawings. It allows properties of the model to be changed, issue, date of issue etc.

The idea is to open the drawing, update issue, date, etc. (save as pdf and dwg). It works, properties changed, and saves the correct view.

The property changes are not saved to the model, unless I open the model and force a save, hence when I reopen the drawing/model they revert to the old.
How can I force a save of the model, even if it is not open?

See last few lines for my attempt:

```vb
Sub WriteModelProperties(swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks, swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2)
Dim element As Integer
Dim boolstatus As Boolean
Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
Dim fieldName As String
Dim fieldType As Integer
Dim fieldValue As String

For element = 0 To 25
    fieldName = propertiesValue(0, element)
    Select Case propertiesValue(1, element)
        Case "Text": fieldType = 30
        Case "Date": fieldType = 64
    End Select
    Set ctrl = UserForm1.Controls(propertiesValue(2, element)) 'to make a compact code
        
    Select Case propertiesValue(3, element)
        Case "Caption": fieldValue = ctrl.Caption
        Case "Value": fieldValue = ctrl.Value
    End Select
    Debug.Print fieldValue
    boolstatus = swCustProp.Add3(fieldName, fieldType, fieldValue, swCustomPropertyDeleteAndAdd)
Next element

swModel.Rebuild (swRebuildAll)
swModel.EditRebuild3 ' Update model properties     
swModel.ViewZoomtofit2
boolstatus = swModel.Save3(swSaveAsOptions_Silent, lErrors, lWarnings)
End Sub
```

Comment: If you read the documentation it clearly states the prerequisite is that the object must be open before you can save it. This is true in every software not just SolidWorks. https://help.solidworks.com/2022/english/api/sldworksapi/Save_File_Example_VB.htm

Comment: Your method accepts a model. You would need to open it and pass the object to this method; https://help.solidworks.com/2022/english/api/sldworksapi/open_advanced_dialog_on_open_example_vb.htm

Comment: True, but opening the drawing loads the model in the background ... does it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry ... tad bit of egg on my face ... it didnt work had to split parts and assemblies  :(

This appears to work ... my apologies if its an insult to vba.
You only need to open the drawing, not the part or assembly :) Sorry couldn't resist.

```
Option Explicit
    Public swApp        As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Public swModDoc     As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim swView          As SldWorks.View
    Dim swPart          As PartDoc
    Dim swAss           As AssemblyDoc
    Dim boolstatus      As Boolean
    Dim lErrors         As Long 'Varaible to collect Errors
    Dim lWarnings       As Long 'Varaible to collect Errors
        
Sub main()

    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModDoc = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set swView = swModDoc.GetFirstView
    Set swView = swView.GetNextView
    
    If swView.ReferencedDocument.GetType = 1 Then
        Set swPart = swView.ReferencedDocument
        boolstatus = swPart.Save3(swSaveAsOptions_Silent, lErrors, lWarnings)
    ElseIf swView.ReferencedDocument.GetType = 2 Then
        Set swAss = swView.ReferencedDocument
        boolstatus = swAss.Save3(swSaveAsOptions_Silent, lErrors, lWarnings)
    End If
End Sub
```